# Intercept Hardware Search Button to interact with a view

Tags: android, search, onkeydown

I wanted to send along an answer to a question that I had.  I wanted to interact with a view, which is defined in a layout in my res folder, using my phone's search button.  Basically making an onSearchListener.  Here I will show an example on how to press a button in your layout with the search button.

```
    public class SearchIntercept extends Activity{

            boolean activateSearch;    

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
            switch(keycode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
                    SearchManager mSearch = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                    onSearchRequested();
                            activateSearch = true;
                    mSearch.stopSearch();
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.search_example);

            SearchManager mSearch = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_1); 


            // Search Listener
            mSearch.setOnCancelListener(new SearchManager.OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                                    if (activateSearch == ture){
                    button.setPressed(true);
                                    activateSearch = false;
                                    }                   
                }
            });
       }
    }
```

So what I do here is grab the key input and then start a search request.  I then cancel that request immediately which allows me to use the OnCancelListener that is built into the SearchManager.  At this point you can take the request and do anything you want with it just like a normal listener.  If you have a different way to do this please let us know in the answers.  Also if I should post this in a different way please let me know, unfortunately I'm still a noob.

Comment: One thing with this that I've found is it will recall the onCancelListener when you back out of the Activity.  I'll update a fix on that soon.

Comment: Updated and fixed.  When exiting there is a lifecycle search canceling thingy.  All you have to do is add a boolean so it can tell the difference between you're proposeful cancel the systems cancel.